# Bulk User Deletion

Tags: plugins, multisite, buddypress

I've created a WordPress 3.0 site w/ MultiSite enabled and the BuddyPress plugin installed (latest available versions of each).  Initially, the site did not have a captcha enabled and now there are hundreds of spam accounts created.

By default, the Super Admin panel for Users only shows 15 users at a time.  I need to delete several hundred users and going through this page by page is monotonous.

Is there plugin available which would assist with bulk user deletion?  I'd like to be able to select and delete a few hundred users at a time (or even better do a regex search by username).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super Admin > Users. Screen Options (top right) > Show on screen __ users.

Be careful, listing hundreds of users could kill your server. Heh!

Comment: Thanks! I set it to 200 and the server handled it just fine.